# Kusto Query: Join tables with different datatypes

Tags: join, azure-data-explorer, kql

How would you join two tables based on two columns with same names, but different datatypes?
In this example, phone_number is string in table_1 and int64 in table_2. When I try to change datatype from string to int, it changes the values!

```
table_1
|project name, phone_number
|join kind=fullouter table_2 on $left.name==$right.name and $left.phone_number==$right.phone_number
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issues with your data to begin with.

A phone number is of type string, not an integer.
A phone number might have a leading zero, e.g., *050123456* or non-digit characters e.g.,   *+972123456* or **1234*.

If you will try to convert those strings to integer, you will get nulls.
If you convert your integers to string, you will discover that for some of the values you are missing a leading zero.

---

That said, in this specific case, I would recommend converting string to integer, paraphs after removing any non-digit character.

```
let table_1 = datatable(name:string, phone_number:string)
[
    "John"  ,"050123456"
   ,"Linda" ,"+972123456"
   ,"Ben"   ,"*1234"
   ,"Pam"   ,"012-333-444"  
];
let table_2 = datatable(name:string, phone_number:long)
[
    "John"  ,50123456
   ,"Linda" ,972123456
   ,"Ben"   ,1234
   ,"Pam"   ,12333444
];
table_1
| project name, phone_number = tolong(replace_regex(phone_number, @"\D+", ""))
| join kind=fullouter table_2 on $left.name==$right.name and $left.phone_number==$right.phone_number
```

| name | phone_number | name1 | phone_number1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 50123456 | John | 50123456 |
| Linda | 972123456 | Linda | 972123456 |
| Ben | 1234 | Ben | 1234 |
| Pam | 12333444 | Pam | 12333444 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42QPU/DMBCGd0v5DyerQ0Jd1MYpCFAkhJgQAztFkdtckxTHjowjMfDjsZsPpREDns7PnV8/OokWrNhLzDaQQi6sON9CJWq8/7KmUgWDptQKM9XWezQ9jALyHhBwh77oUlEARtfb9SbmyfaGnjuMvlYqF9QVy7vb%20LL1hP6NK648H%20ibqDvqglac81WSJA4E5OMhIHJUjf%20pKvWfooPmzHJ0nCl6OPNziHPn1on1%20wvIDzRGn/BgwTtdyjhlq71QaLCR4oCZwQK/w%20kMg0e6e15SBpRGkc876UrBpxNMj62UurUuaNiBVrCQeLTX/rM0XZiqKLsLCJX3vWn8ODOFv9hnG/0BAgAA)

Comment: That is exactly true. I was trying to convert the int one to string. Do you have any suggestions as how to do a datatype conversion while joining? Thanks